# Why my right edge of the Box in Compose is vibrating while expanding and collapsing?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-animation

[Animation is not at all smooth enough, it is just like lagging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bz5lf.gif)

Here I am using a simple box, I am expanding its width using **animateFloatAsState**. Without any animation of its inside element, it is not at all smooth enough. Where I am doing wrong?

Code:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.animation.core.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.clickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxHeight
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color

class TestClassTwo : ComponentActivity() {

    private var isExpandedSavingCard by mutableStateOf(true)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {

            val savingCardWeight = remember {
                mutableStateOf(0.50f)
            }
            val animation = animateFloatAsState(
                targetValue = savingCardWeight.value,
                animationSpec = tween(
                    durationMillis = 400,
                    easing = LinearEasing
                )
            )

            Box(modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(animation.value)
                .fillMaxHeight(0.5f)
                .clickable {
                    isExpandedSavingCard = !isExpandedSavingCard
                    savingCardWeight.value = if (isExpandedSavingCard) 0.50f else 1f
                }
                .background(color = Color.Blue))
            {


            }


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem in jetpack compose till now but you can reduce lagging effect by changing two line of code

from

**durationMillis = 400,
easing = LinearEasing**

To

**durationMillis = 2000,
easing = LinearOutSlowInEasing**

**Note ->** durationMillis = 2000 just for increase time of animation you can use any time above 1000 ms